# jQuery equivalent of document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of JavaScript code that I want to translate it to jQuery:

```
 var target = document.getElementById('myID');

 ... do additional work here ...
```

The code above works just fine, no problem. However if I try to use it this way, nothing happens:

```
 var target =  $("#myID");
```

What is the equivalent of `document.getElementById` in jQuery?

P.S. jQuery library is loaded and the code is withing

```
    $(document).ready(function () {


       var target = document.getElementById('myID');

       ... do additional work here ...


       var target =  $("#myID");

    });
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Included Jquery library..? getting any errors like `$ is not defined` displaying in the console.?

Comment: "do additional work here" what is the additional work there?

Comment: This is the most basic thing you can do in jQuery. Have you tried debugging in *any* way? Included jquery.js? Checked the console for errors? Does the element actually exist on DOM load? Included a DOM Ready handler?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy , I am sure you are right the OP should not include Jquery library

Comment: jQuery is loaded because I use it previously in the code so nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Also note that a jQuery selector returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element, so if your `'additional work' code relies on native element properties you will get errors.

Comment: and yes the code is withing $(document).ready() ...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think that is the problem. He must tried to implement dom object functionalities with jquery object

Comment: Thanks @undefined it works! Didn't knew about the get(0) ... :) great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @undefined pointed in a comment above, the correct answer is:

```
var target = $("#myID").get(0);
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? You can answer your own question, no?

Comment: @undefined: actually you answered my question :) but whatever :) you can answer and I will mark it as correct!

Comment: @David Dury - +1 ,you asked good question but you didn't know how to post the question more understandable for others

Comment: @Sudharsan: I just wanted to know the jQuery equivalent of document.getElementById. And as I pointed out the document.getElementById it was working correct. Maybe I should have mentioend that jQuery was loaded and in place.

Comment: @DavidDury - Then your title be in your comment -  "jQuery equivalent of document.getElementById"

Answer (score 1):

how about `var target =  $("#myID")[0];`

recently i debug the code :

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myId"), mapOptions);
```

it works well only with getElementById , and the `$("#myID")` not work.

Answer (score 1):

try this code it will help you..

```
var target = $("#myID")[0];
```

thanks